# SQL Server : how to select the rows in a table with the same value on a column but some exact values on another column for the grouped rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table with some sample data:

```
Supplier_ID Product_ID  Stock
-----------------------------
1             272          1
1             123          5
1             567          3
1             564          3
2             272          4
2             12           3
2             532          1
3             123          4
3             272          5
```

I want to check the suppliers that have both products: `272` and `123`, so the result would be like:

```
Supplier_ID
-----------
1
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT A.Supplier_ID FROM
 (SELECT Supplier_ID FROM Your_Table WHERE Product_ID = 272) AS A
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT Supplier_ID FROM Your_Table WHERE Product_ID = 123) AS B
   ON A.Supplier_ID = B.Supplier_ID
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Supplier_ID
FROM your_tab
WHERE Product_ID IN (272, 123)
GROUP BY Supplier_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID) = 2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406012)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works using **set operations**. IMHO a too little used feature of databases.

```
select Supplier_ID from table1 where product_id=272
intersect
select Supplier_ID from table1 where product_id=123
```

it produces as well

```
Supplier_ID
1
3
```

By the way a **distinct** is not needed due to **intersect** delivers distinct rows.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13b11/3

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code: By Using **Row_number()**

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY [Supplier_ID]
                    ORDER BY [Supplier_ID]) AS rn
         FROM   #Your_Table
         WHERE  Product_ID IN ( 272, 123 ))
SELECT DISTINCT Supplier_ID
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn > 1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Supplier_ID
1
3
```